getElementById in PHP async function
I am writing a php where one of its function is to scrape data from internet. This time I try to use guzzle directly in PHP. Here is my script:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>     
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>contacts.php</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    $tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong';
    $timestamp = time();
    $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
    $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp

    $chin_gov_html = 'https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/wr/' . substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),0, 4) . substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),5, 2) . '/'. substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),8, 2) . 'c.htm';
  
    $rootFolder = dirname(__DIR__);
    require_once $rootFolder.'/Bulletin Translator/private/lib/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');

    // Send an asynchronous request.
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $chin_gov_html);
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) 
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $body = (string) $response->getBody();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML($body);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    

        $bulltin_name = $xpath->evaluate('//body/div/div/div/ul/li/a');
        foreach($bulltin_name as $element)
        {
            print_r($element->textContent."<br>");
        }

        $bulltin_url = $xpath->evaluate('//body/div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href');
        foreach($bulltin_url as $url)
        {
            print_r($url->textContent."<br>");
        }
    });

    $promise->wait();
?>
</body>
</html>

Everthing is fine in this step that the result can be scrapped smoothly. Now, I want to go one step further. Instead of printing the result directly on the doc, I want to display my result inside an element I defined just like the "document.getElementById().innerHTML" method in javascript.
The reason why I want to do so is that I hope the new scraping result can always replace the old one after user clicks a scraping button in another html page (not shown here) in future development.I add the following script in my php after $doc = new DOMDocument();:
$node = $doc->createElement("p", '');

$newnode = $doc->appendChild($node); 
$attr = $newnode->setAttributeNode(new DOMAttr('id', 'result'));
$newnode->setIDAttribute('id', true);

However,

Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "textContent"

is returned. What shall I do to assign my scraping result to the element I appointed?

you can generate a <script> tag in your PHP, and have the code in there do document.getElementById().innerHTML = whatever

I add  directly in the body tag and I replace the print_r script with the following one:   echo ''.""; However, it simply returns the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '氣'"

The value needs to be in quotes. Use .innerHTML = ' . json_encode($element->textContent) . '; </script><br>';

Thank you, Barmar. It works pefectly for me now.
